# Firebase error: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add game score in firebase when the game ends. I don't know much about Firebase, i follow some steps and get till here. Now its showing a error of some Future type. I think its just a small mistake, Please help me to solve this error

**Storing Data in Firebase (Code)**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScoreMethods {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final uid = "";

  getUserId() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      String uid = user.uid;
      return uid;
    } else {
      print('No user signed in.');
    }
  }

  Future<String> addUserScores(
      {required int score,
      required String gameCategory,
      required String gameName}) async {
    //Creating Path to game database
    try {
      String userId = getUserId();
      var userRef =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId);
      var gameCategoryRed = userRef.collection('gameScore').doc('category');
      var gameCollectionRef =
          gameCategoryRed.collection(gameCategory).doc(gameName);

      //Creating path to fetch details
      var totalRoundData = await gameCollectionRef.get();
      var totalRoundsPlayed = totalRoundData.data()!['totalRoundsPlayed'];

      var roundNumber = 'round_${totalRoundsPlayed + 1}';

      await gameCollectionRef
          .collection('rounds')
          .doc(roundNumber)
          .set({'score': score});

      await gameCollectionRef.update({
        'totalRoundsPlayed': totalRoundsPlayed + 1,
      });

      print("Data added");
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return 'success';
  }
}
```

Calling addUserScore from different page:

```
await scoreMethods.addUserScores(gameCategory: 'decison_making', gameName: 'flappy_bird', score: score);
```

**This is my Firebase Structure**
[image: Firebase Structure]

Firebase Structure:

```
Users:
  uid:
      - mail
      - username
    gameScore:
       category:
           decison_making:
                  flappy_bird:
                              - totalRoundsPlayed
                           round{}:
                                    - score
           paying_attention:
           remembering:
```

Errors:

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0):

As i said, it was a small mistake,

I just needed to call await, before calling the function getUserId in game page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).